# Whence visa "stamp"?

Tags: terminology, word-usage, subcontinental-english, government

This question is inspired by https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69496/whats-the-deal-with-stamping-us-visas.

The US government calls the visa sticker that is inserted into a passport a *foil.*  It is also undeniably a *sticker,* and the Schengen Visa Code indeed calls it a sticker.

Some countries use inked stamps on the passport page to insert a visa, but the US does not.  Nonetheless, there is much material on the internet concerning US visa "stamps," and the "stamping" of US visas (that is, the insertion of a visa foil into a passport).

My impression is that this terminology has for some reason been introduced by Indian and other South Asian workers, but this is largely based on my encountering the terminology mostly in material posted by such people.

Is it possible to confirm whether this hypothesis is correct?

If the hypothesis is incorrect, where did this usage originate?

Comment: What do you call the little stickers you affix to the top-right corner of envelopes before mailing them?

Comment: @DanBron a stamp, of course. In my opinion the sticker in a passport is too large to be called a stamp. Also stamps tend to have a monetary face value, which visa stickers do not. But none of that is really pertinent to the question.

Comment: If these pleasures not thee move, you may consider that visas were (probably) *stamped* long before they were *stuck*, and bureaucratese is a fairly conservative language. The name *stuck*, ha ha. But I still think it's fine to call some kind of official sticker a *stamp*. I'll noodle on other contexts which you might find more convincing. Meanwhile, here's a literal definition from [a dictionary](https://www.wordnik.com/words/stamp), with no mention of fave value etc: "A small piece of paper bearing a design on one side and adhesive on the other.".

Comment: @DanBron I understand all of that. My question is not about the logical origin of the term, but its geographical origin. More precisely, I would like to know whether its use originated with a particular language community.

Comment: A quick Google nGrams search reveals that "visa stamp" is used in US Immigrations law by American immigration courts, lawyers, and other officials, e.g. [*Cases Adjudged, Volume 311*, United States. Court of Appeals (District of Columbia Circuit)](http://j.mp/1P7RE0E), [*Introducing the 1996 immigration reform act*, R. Patrick Murphy, ‎American Immigration Lawyers Association](http://bit.ly/1RPgq5o), etc, and I imagine the people you're seeing use the term have lots of interaction with these US officials, e.g. in applying for or appealing visa decisions, and are merely adopting th terminology.

Comment: @phoog i think your attempt to pin the use of the word "stamp" on asian migrant workers is very misguided.

Comment: FWIW, the full text of @DanBron's first reference is [here](http://caselaw.findlaw.com/us-dc-circuit/1051467.html), and clearly seems to concern an actual ink stamp.

Comment: @MaxWilliams evidence to the contrary is welcome. Please post an answer if you have it.

Comment: @HenningMakholm but the second reference clearly supports the hypothesis that the term has been current among immigration lawyers for some time.

Comment: @phoog There's plenty of evidence to the contrary in the comments already I think.

Comment: @MaxWilliams one citation isn't "plenty of evidence."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Some countries use inked stamps on the passport page to insert a visa, but the **US does not**. Nonetheless, there is much material on the internet concerning US visa "stamps," and the "stamping" of US visas (that is, the insertion of a visa foil into a passport).

At one time US visa was actual ink stamps, the sticker and the foil are relatively new trend and terms. In 1990, I received F-1 Student visa stamp on my passport at US embassy New Delhi. The visa was an actual multi-colored ink stamp and not a sticker or foil.

In 1992, when I renewed my student visa, the new visa with my monochrome photo was directly printed on the passport page using a printer.

It is not a South Asian or Indian specific term.